# How to get multiple return values when calling c++ from lua scripts?

Tags: c++, lua

```
//c++ funciton definition
int LS_SomeFucntion(LuaState* state)
{
LuaStack args(state);
//.. 
set<int>::iterator it = mySet.begin();
for(; it != mySet.end(); ++it)
{
    state.pushInteger(*it);
}
return mySet.size();

}

state->GetGlobals().Register("SomeFunction",LS_SomeFunction);

//lua scripts
??? = SomeFunction()
```

How to get the return value of SomeFunction() in lua scripts
when the size is not know when the function is called?

Comment: It appears you're not using the standard C API for Lua. What C++ binding are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture all the return values in a table:

```
local rv = { SomeFunction() }

print('SomeFunction returned', #rv, 'values')
for i,val in ipairs(rv) do
    print(i,val)
```

Or process them using a variable parameter list:

```
function DoSomething(...)
   local nargs = select('#', ...)
   print('Received', nargs, 'arguments')
   for i=1,nargs do
      print(i,select(i,...))
end

DoSomething(SomeFunction())
```

Of course, your C function should probably just return a Lua table containing the list items. I'm not familiar with the LuaPlus, but judging from the documentation [here](http://wwhiz.com/LuaPlus/LuaPlus.html), you'd want something like this:

```
int LS_SomeFunction(LuaState* state)
{
   LuaObject table;
   table.AssignNewTable(state, mySet.size()); // presize the array portion

   int i = 1;
   for(set<int>::iterator it = mySet.begin(); it != mySet.end(); ++it)
       table.SetNumber(i++, *it);

   table.PushStack();
   return 1;
}
```

Then you just say:

```
local rv = SomeFunction()
print('SomeFunction returned', #rv, 'values')
```